# PhpStorm Live Templates: Applicable ONLY in Blade (.blade.php)?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

When creating Live Template in PhpStorm (10), I have to choose where it will be applicable. The problem is that there is no option for **Blade files** (**.blade.php**), so I have to choose PHP (**.php**) which is not the best solution because those templates are specific just for Blade. Is there any way to make my Live Templates applicable only in Blade (.blade.php)?

Comment: There is no Blade-specific context for Live Templates. You can file a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: [is this what you're looking for?](https://github.com/koomai/phpstorm-laravel-live-templates) It's a bit more all-inclusive, but probably waht you want

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No, I have my own Live Templates and I just wanted to make them applicable only in Blade (.blade.php) files, but it seems that is not possible for now (as **LazyOne** wrote: "There is no Blade-specific context for Live Templates").

Comment: @PeraMika Isn't that what they're achieving in their Blade example?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No, as you can see [here](https://github.com/koomai/phpstorm-laravel-live-templates/blob/master/Laravel_Form.xml) - all those templates are applicable in HTML and PHP files (but, of course, all those Blade templates work fine since Blade files are actually PHP files... but it would be even nicer if we would be able to make them applicable only in Blade... ).

Comment: Totally gotcha, sorry for the confusion there. Best of luck!